# HERE Map does not support hi-IN? Language support and mappings?

Tags: here-api

We are trying to integrate localization into our HERE JS map display. This involves both the map labels and the UI options.

We are using these JS libraries:

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

On our website, we are using language codes following the ISO language codes: http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm

However, when I try to pass in a standard code like "hi-IN" into the defaultLayers creation:

```
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(hereMap, maptypes, "hi-IN"); // simplified, language code is actually passed in
```

Looking at the HERE API documentation: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/maps/map-multi-language-support it seems like I'm using the right kind of language code, but I get `"Uncaught Error: Locale [hi-IN] is not supported."`. Am I misunderstanding something or using something incorrectly? Is there a list of all the Locales *are* supported?

If it's not supposed, does anyone have recommendations on how to create our own translations for the map labels like "normal" and "satellite"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently "hi-IN" is not supported yet. 
About the map labels in UI. Please see below thread in SOF.
The snipped sample code is about creating own UI control.

[How do I get a Terrain Map in UI Controls HERE Maps v3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136959/how-do-i-get-a-terrain-map-in-ui-controls-here-maps-v3-1)

I hope this help.

Comment: Is there a way to also customize the text "Choose View" that is shown above the layer options? Thank you.

Comment: There is a tricky way to change "Choose View"  -->  var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
ui.u.a["layers.choose"]  = "translated"

Comment: I'm getting the error: "cannot read property 'a' of undefined". Is this for version 3.0?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('H_rdo_title')[0].innerHTML = 'Custom Text';