# HERE-API: How to change the tile types in the "Choose View" options

Tags: javascript, here-api

in the default Here Map, there is a "Choose View" button in the bottom right corner. This can be seen in many maps, for example here:
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/maps/map-at-specified-location

The user has the choice between "Map View" and "Satellite". How can I change the tile type of these two views? For example, how can I change the tile type of the "Map View" to "raster.terrain.xbase"?

Currently I can set the Tile Type to xbase when I init the map, but when the user switches views the tile type gets overriden with the default.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who might have the same problem: I found a solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329212/how-to-create-custom-labels-for-here-map-ui-labels-3-0) and updated it for Here Maps 3.1.

You can remove the default mapSettings and create your own `H.ui.MapSettingsControl`:

```
// remove default mapsettings
ui.removeControl('mapsettings');

// store scalebar
const scalebar = ui.getControl('scalebar');
ui.removeControl('scalebar');

// Create custom mapSettings
const mapSettings = new H.ui.MapSettingsControl({
    baseLayers: [
        {
            label: 'Layer 1',
            layer: defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        },
        {
            label: 'Layer 2',
            layer: defaultLayers.raster.terrain.xbase,
        },
    ],
});

// Add Map Settings and scalebar
ui.addControl('custom-mapsettings', mapSettings);
ui.addControl('scalebar', scalebar);
```

The MapSettingsControl accepts an array of base layers and an array of layers, as you can see in the [official documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-ui-mapsettingscontrol.html).
These layers are then displayed in the choose view dialog.

Comment: is it possible to change layers programatically? I have to remove all the control (zoom, mapsettings, scale) from the UI but I need to change the layer at runtime.